# TinyMCE with paid-plugins in public facing page

Tags: tinymce, api-key

On a website, I use TinyMCE in the admin via the CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/THE_SECRET_KEY/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
```

I will build a public page (available to anyone) where we want to use TinyMCE too. I understand that I can download the free core version of TinyMCE but we also want the pro plugins which I assume I can't download.

Is it OK to expose the KEY (since it's domain limited)?

Or is there an obvious solution I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is domain-limited, so there are no issues having the API key in the URL.

Comment: Thanks. Confirmed with their support team. Apparently we need to pay more to self-host with pro-plugins like `powerpaste`.